# How to use Regex to match discontinuous strings

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook

This question is probably simple for others, but I'm new to `RegEx` and to this forum, and haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

I have emails coming into Microsoft Outlook that generally look like this:

---

> Patient:       SMITH, JANE
>
> MRN:           12345678
>
> EncounterID:   1234567890
>
> EncounterDate:     Apr 11 2017 12:00AM
>
> Department:    NEUROLOGY
>
> Center:        Headache
>
> Location:      Main Campus
>
> Visit Type:    NEW NEUR HEADACHE
>
> Attending Phys:    JONES, MARY
>
> ---

I want to have Outlook examine each email as it arrives, select those whose subject line indicates that they have relevant information, then extract the MRN, Last Name of patient, First Name of patient, and Encounter Date.

When a new email arrives, my module runs the following Sub:

```
Public Sub ProcessImatchKpEmails(item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim LastName As String
Dim FirstName As String
Dim EncounterDate As String
Dim MRN As String
Dim Body As String

On Error Resume Next

'   Check to make sure it is an Outlook mail message.
    If TypeName(item) <> "MailItem" Then Exit Sub
    Body = item.Body

'   Exract data from the email
    If item.Subject =  _
        gImatchKpEmailSubjectNo Or item.Subject = _ 
        gImatchKpEmailSubjectYes Or _
        item.Subject=_gImatchKpEmailSubjectMaybe Then
           MRN = ExtractText(Body, RegPattern("MRN"))
           LastName = ExtractText(Body, RegPattern("LastName"))
           FirstName = ExtractText(Body, RegPattern("FirstName"))
           EncounterDate = ExtractText(Body, RegPattern("EncounterDate"))
    End If
End Sub
```

The `RegPattern` function looks like this:

```
Public Function RegPattern(Lookup As String) As String 'Creates a 
  regPattern for each type of lookup

On Error Resume Next

    Select Case Lookup
        Case "LastName"
            RegPattern = "Patient\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)\s*"
        Case "FirstName"
            RegPattern = "Patient\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)[,](\w*)\s*"
        Case "EncounterDate"
            RegPattern = "EncounterDate\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)\s*" 
        Case "MRN"
            RegPattern = "MRN\s*[:]+\s*(\d*)\s*"
    End Select

    Debug.Print Lookup, RegPattern

End Function
```

The `ExtractText` Function looks like this:

```
Public Function ExtractText(Str As String, RegPattern As String) As 
   String
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim numMatches As MatchCollection
Dim M As Match

On Error Resume Next

regEx.Pattern = RegPattern

Set numMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
If numMatches.Count = 0 Then
    ExtractText = "missing"
Else
    Set M = numMatches(0)
    ExtractText = M.SubMatches(0)
End If

Debug.Print ExtractText
End Function
```

When I run this, the code picks up the new email, and it manages to pull the MRN (12345678) and Last Name of Patient (Smith) accurately.

However, it also pulls the First Name of Patient as (Smith).  Similarly, it pulls the Encounter Date as (Apr), but loses the rest.

Can anybody tell me what the appropriate `RegEx` code would be to get the patient's first name, as well as the entire Encounter Date?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can Outlook run vbscript code ?

Comment: But, examining your regex one at a time, this `Patient\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)\s*` will only match one group of words. I assume that is the last name. Also, does vbsctipt (or vba?) follow double quoting rules (i.e. escapes have to be escaped) ?

Comment: Ok, so looks like you should use 1 regex to get the Last,First name at once. Use the one for `First` name and get _last_ in group 1 and _first_ in group 2. A suggestion: if it doesn't have a first name, don't require it in the regex. `Patient\s*[:]+(?:\s*(\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(\w+))?)?`

Comment: A note - Regex is fairly universal, some people that know regex very well, may not know your language usage. Other people that know your language usage may not know regex very well. It's up to you to prioritize your question as to which aspect will help you the most. Otherwise, garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Thank you sin.  Your suggested code worked exactly as I'd hoped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is complex and could be interesting - but the actual problem is minor and does not provide insight for others. The original problem was solved with a short answer not useful to others.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> "Patient\s*[:]+\s*(\w*)[,](\w*)\s*"
> ```

The core problem is that you always extract the 0th submatch; but you have two sets of capturing parentheses. Changing the first set of parentheses into non-capturing ones should help:

```
"Patient\s*[:]+\s*(?:\w*)[,](\w*)\s*"
```

Or even having no parentheses for the first name, as there's no reason why you should need grouping there.

Also note that `[:]` is identical to `:`, and you probably want to capture at least one character for names, which is `\w+` instead of `\w*`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.